# zsh displaying my name weird

Tags: zsh

Upon installing `zsh`, the shell has displayed my name like

```
[\u@\h \W]\$
```

I tried adding

```
PROMPT='%n>'
```

to my `.zshrc`, but it does not seem to have helped.

Comment: That's a bash setting. You have a bash setting somewhere it shouldn't be.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Installed oh-my-zsh and everything seems to be working fine. Problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

Your `.zshrc` line should be

```
PS1='%n>'
```

Comment: hmm, this doesn't seem to help, even after rebooting.

Comment: Nitpick: there is no need to export `PS1`. It is sufficient to just set it within the same shell context, which is the case when it is set in the configuration file (or sourced from another file with `source FILE` or `. FILE`). It also may lead to broken prompts when starting a different shell, as demonstrated in OP's question.

Comment: @Adaephon Good to know. Thank you for the information. I guess i have some reading to do on export. Updating my answer.